# Can C# be used in embedded environments?

Tags: c#, embedded

As I'm learning C# and my budding interest in embedded devices, I wondered If I can use C# in an embedded environment. How is C# going to help us in the realm of the Internet Of Things.

Note: The only question I found that resemble  this is this one: [C# for embedded devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568266/c-sharp-for-embedded-systems)

But this question has been asked 3 years ago. Obviously many things have changed since then.

Comment: Instead of "obviously..." conider checking out answers to question you've linked and see if tools/technologies in question are still there. Note that general search for tools better suited to http://softwarerects.stackexchange.com

Comment: Make that http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are at least three ways:

- Through the [.Net Micro Framework](https://netmf.codeplex.com/), however .Net MF is supported on a limited range of architectures, has a footprint of around 300Kb, and is not a hard real-time OS - thus precluding it form a large section of embedded applications. Although originally a Microsoft product, it is now an open source project.
- The [.NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f44bbwa1(v=vs.90).aspx) running on Windows Embedded CE or Windows Mobile.
- Through [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) running on embedded Linux.

C# requires a runtime environment that is not insubstantial which is its biggest barrier to embedded deployment in many applications.  However if you have a platform with resources in the order of 4Mb ROM, and 1Mb RAM, or sufficient to support CE or Linux, then it is entirely possible.  For high volumes or high value products, with complex UI and connectivity requirements it may make sense, but for simple applications it may be hardly worth the resource overhead and hardware cost.

Comment: Thank you very much for actually answering my question